# can't figure out initialization error - java

Tags: java

I can not for the life of me figure out why I'm getting a "variable key might not have been initialized" error. I've entered my entire code because if I remove the BufferedReader and set the string equal to  I don't get the error. Also, if I leave the BufferedReader part in and remove the StringBuffer part, string key initializes just fine. Please help! New to java (and programming in general).

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class reverseString {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String cipher = "";
        String input = "";
        String newCipher;
        String ouput = "";

        BufferedReader readerKeyword = null;
        String key;
        try {
            readerKeyword = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("keyword.txt"));          
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfex) {
            System.out.println(fnfex.getMessage() + " File not found.");
            System.exit(0); 
        }
        try {
            while ((key = readerKeyword.readLine()) !=null) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            System.out.println(ioex.getMessage() + " Unable to read file.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int len = abc.length();
        for(int i = len -1;i>=0;i--)
            cipher = cipher + abc.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(abc);
        System.out.println(cipher);
        newCipher = sb.append(key + cipher).toString();
        System.out.println(newCipher);
        System.out.println(removeDuplicates(newCipher));
   }

   static String removeDuplicates(String newCipher) {
       char[] charArr = newCipher.toCharArray();
       Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
       for(char ch : charArr) {
           charSet.add(ch);
       }
       StringBuffer StrBuf = new StringBuffer();
       for(char c : charSet) {
           StrBuf.append(c);
       }
       return StrBuf.toString();
   }
}
```

Was is not initialized in the while loop at line28?

Comment: initialization within a while loop or a try block is not guaranteed to have happened. You must explicitly initialize local variables with some default value, and for a String consider using `""`.

Comment: Hint: The compiler does not realize that `System.exit(...)` calls do not return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE and Compiler shows it when it is not guaranteed initialization for safety/precaution. Do this and it should go away,

```
BufferedReader readerKeyword = null;
String key = null;
```

However, do make sure that it gets initialized.

It is not guaranteed initialization because it is inside a try-catch block and if you get an exception, you can get by without initialization because, you are handling it.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain anything?

Comment: It's a compile error, not some IDE warning. And a multiple-times-dupe.

Comment: @pvg : My bad, I also assumed, his IDE must be showing it too because Eclipse and Intellij do before compiler shows it.

Comment: @pulp_fiction I tried setting it equal to null, and it returns as null, so my output for System.out.println(key); is null, not the text in the files.

Comment: @sfrank : I told you, setting it null is to bypass the compiler warning and that you have to ensure it actually gets initialized. You will have to debug the assignment statement to see why it is not getting initialized.

Comment: @pvg I mentioned in the OP that if certain parts of the code are removed then the variable is initialized. So MY question hasn't been answered several times. My question I guess becomes, am I using the StringBuffer appropriately here if it causing my string to no longer be initialized?

Comment: @sfrank : Would you mind posting the parts that make the error go away?

Comment: Initialize it to a Null String: `String key = "";` since null is taboo in the location you're having the problem. You should also be carrying through with the **StringBuffer.append()** method in the line: `newCipher = sb.append(key + cipher).toString();`. It would be better as: `newCipher = sb.append(key).append(cipher).toString();`.

Comment: @sfrank post a [MCVE] that shows the thing that reproduces your specific problem/unclear bit.

Comment: @pulp_fiction When I comment out the StringBuffer and the static String removeDuplicates(String newCipher), String key is initialized and set to the contents of the .txt file during the while loop.

Comment: @sfrank : Go to ideone.com and post the code there then RUN it and copy the URL and post that here.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I also tried setting it to ""; and it also returned "null". I'm wondering if I need to handle the appending in a separate method other than main?

Comment: @sfrank : That means, its getting initialized in the middle somewhere. You can debug to see exactly whats happening.

Comment: @pulp_fiction  http://ideone.com/1TC5t6 I'm not familiar with this site. Do I need to create a .java file or point it to my file?

Comment: @sfrank : Copy your code to there and run it.

Comment: @pulp_fiction     ideone.com/1TC5t6     how does it know where to find my .txt files? Sorry I'm such a noob!

Comment: Of course key = null, it's because your **while** loop wont end until it does. I believe what you want to do is reverse the characters of each line read in from file and display those lines in console is it not? Your cipher code should be in your while loop. I dunno..I may have this all wrong as to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Bingo!! There is was, thank you! I put the StringBuffer in the while loop and its perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @pulp_fiction thank you as well! I'll keep looking into ideone.com. seems like a very useful tool if I can figure it out.